# How do handle Error return types in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function that can return either an object of type Person or an Error.
I want to conditionally read the values of keys in the returned object if it's not an Error.

The last line of the code snippet below gives an error:

**Property 'firstName' does not exist on type 'Person | Error'**

The error can be seen [at this link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyyMwUGYAcnALYQBcyFUoA5gNxHIA2cF1dRkzAsQHAgF8CBGAFcQCMMBzJWUCBEhQAFAAdMORunI4AlEYO4APsgCiUKFij4uxYDGR7LAOlLkqtCgAvCHIAOQAsnDcCFjcNGGmLsQpKepgslC4IBAA7nYOTtphACoAFsAYJGT8gciVyCBYYMjR3Fi5EAAmiZypUqnpmbiEqcR+tYLI+iYgvjUBdAA0rim8kwzTPuuLECv9nFIEsSAUyAAeyEGq6prQ2qMpE7uMAERRMXE0r-trfC-EV4AJQgAE8mtwuhgfpJTJxjjgznhqv4BHseP80cgJFcLpwgA).

```js
interface Person {
  firstName: string;
  lastName:  string;
}

function greeter(person: Person): Person | Error {
    if (person.firstName === 'Malcolm') {
        return new Error('This firstName is not allowed');
    }
    return {
      firstName: person.firstName,
      lastName: person.lastName,
    };
}

const x = greeter({
    firstName: "Malcolm",
    lastName:  "Reynolds",
});

const { firstName, lastName } = x;
```

I have to return the Error for some scenarios.
Can't skip it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to check if the `x` is of a type of Person before you do your deconstruction.  And then to make typescript shut up, `const { firstName, lastName } = x as Person;`

Comment: @Taplar, great!
This worked. Thanks :)

Comment: Why not simply throw the error and let the caller catch it? Then you don't need to worry about crazy type unioning.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would suggest you to wrap `greeter()` inside `try ... catch` block to handle the error.

Still if you want to do it this way, you can do the following.

```js
const val = greeter({
    firstName: "Malcolm",
    lastName:  "Reynolds",
})

if (typeof val == Person) { 
const x = val as Person;
const {firstName, lastName} = x;
}
```

**Here you can check the type of result and perform operation accordingly.**